# Retrieve chromosome number with just RSID?

Tags: bioconductor

I have ~500,000 rsids - but want which chromosome each SNP resides on. How can I do this?

```
MarkerName A1 A2 
rs2326918 a g 
rs7929618 c g 
rs66941928 t c
```

I want the chromosome number associated with each MarkerName. So the output would be like this:

```
MarkerName A1 A2 Chr
rs2326918 a g     6 
rs7929618 c g     6
rs66941928 t c    6
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @workhorse

Comment: I'd recommend consulting the RefSNP documentation https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/docs/RefSNP_about/

Comment: @Workhorse thanks for your question. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer by NiekdeKlein

Answer (score 2):

Download dbsnp VCF file from https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606/VCF/. This contains rs IDs and chromosome info (among other info). Can match your rs IDs to the rs IDs in dbsnp VCF, and extract chromosome from there.

See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/docs/human_variation_vcf/ for more information on the dbsnp files.